# VARMA from the MTS package

Tags: r

I am learning about the VARMA model from the MTS package. I am applying the function on one of the dataset "ibmspko" that I got from `data("mts-examples", package="MTS")`. When I applied the function, I'm getting the below error

> Error in solve.default(xpx, xpy) : 
>     system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.3346e-19

Can someone please explain what this error means and how to resolve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ran the following:

```
library(MTS)

data("mts-examples",package="MTS")

VARMA(ibmspko)
```

You received an error because `ibmspko` has dates in its first column, and this results in a near perfect linear dependence in a certain matrix which should be invertible, but suddenly isn't (computationally). You can either only include the *data* columns:

```
 VARMA(ibmspko[, -1])
```

Or pass in an `mts` object, like this:

```
ibmspko.mts <- ts(ibmspko[,-1],start=c(1961,1),frequency=12)
VARMA(ibmspko.mts)
```